# What's with tvtropes tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I just found *tvtropes* tag on the main site without any warning. Can anyone tell me what purpose does that serve? Can I create ComicVine or SFX or XKCD tags for example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That tag should not exist and I have removed it from the questions it was on.

Comment: Don't you have power to remove the tag fully?

Comment: Not directly, but it gets auto-deleted after 24 hours

Comment: @SS However, should it reappear and become a nuisance, it can be blacklisted